# How do I call the burnFrom() function once my contract is deployed?

Tags: erc-20, ethereumj, openzeppelin-contracts

I'm using the [Openzeppelin library](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity) in my contract where `MyToken is StandardBurnableToken`. Once I deploy that and I want to burn a set amount of the initial supply how do I call the function? I don't see anything in the RPC documents or web3 in read the docs. Do I use my existing wallet and send tokens to a dead wallet?

Comment: You can use this: https://www.myetherwallet.com/#contracts , Try out on Testnet first.

Comment: If you have questions on using OpenZeppelin you can also ask in the Community Forum: https://forum.openzeppelin.com/ 
*Disclosure: I am the Community Manager at OpenZeppelin*

Answer (score 1):

In order to interact with a contract, either use an interface such as the one mentioned by user *A.K.*, or do it programatically. I'm unable to provide tested *ethereumj* code (as tagged), but the *JavaScript* equivalent could be of help as they share similar constructs. The fundamentals are the same.

Consider the following deployed contract derived from `ERC20Burnable` (*ERC20* being the *Standard*, `StandardBurnableToken`) **[1]**:

```
contract MyToken is ERC20Burnable {
    uint256 private _totalSupply = 100;

    constructor() ERC20Burnable() public {
        _mint(msg.sender, _totalSupply);
    }
}
```

Burning a set amount, for example `3`, of the initial supply could be done by calling the `burn` function, as shown in following *JavaScript* code (`burn.js`) using `web3@0.20`:

```
const Web3 = require("web3");                                                                                                                                               
const Tx = require("ethereumjs-tx");
const ABI = require("ethereumjs-abi");
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://rinkeby.infura.io/"));

const contractAbi=[...];
const contractAddress = "0x...";
var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(contractAbi).at(contractAddress);

const accountAddress = "0x...";
var accountNonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(accountAddress);

var rawTransaction = {
    "nonce": web3.toHex(accountNonce),
    "from": accountAddress,
    "to": contractAddress,
    "gasPrice": web3.toHex(10 * 1e9),
    "gasLimit": web3.toHex(1000000),
    "value": 0x0,
    "chainId": 4,
    "data": ABI.simpleEncode("burn(uint256)", "3")
};
var privateKey = "...";
var key = new Buffer(privateKey, "hex");
var tx = new Tx(rawTransaction);
tx.sign(key);

web3.eth.sendRawTransaction("0x"+tx.serialize().toString("hex"), function(error, result){
    if(!error) {
        console.log(result);
    } else {
        console.error(error);
    }
});
```

Provided the dependencies are available, running `node burn.js` results in the transaction hash.

After the transaction is complete, executing the following snippet on the same context as the previous code would inspect the total supply:

```
MyContract.totalSupply(function(error, result){
    console.log("Current total supply: " + result.toString());
})
```

Expected output:

> Current total supply: 97

The `burnFrom(address, uint256)` function is similar, except that it targets a specific address (a token owner) instead of the contract supply.

**[1]** https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Burnable.sol

Stay super!

/Javi